# magento 1.9.0.1 . Plugin error-Duplicate?

Tags: php, magento

I installed time ago "Blog - Community Edition by aheadWorks" by connect manager. Then I removed it. Now im trying to do a manual installation (it doesnt work anymore by connect manager).

Magento 1.9.0.1

Compilation is disabled

Steps I followed:

1)Clear cache and session

2)Follow manual installation guide

3)Clear cache and session

Frontend is ok but beckend doesnt work.

here the error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/blog/observer" already exists";i:1;s:1484:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/blog...', false)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('blog/observer')
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imac/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/imac/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/cdf086fb640a1142d35ef490661f6d5c/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/imac/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

It's a problem caused by some duplicate? What can I do?

---

Shame on me.
I misunderstood the guide.

BTW New problem

Well, it's pretty obvious where is the problem...one table is missing. But solution is? :(
Error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:98:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'imacdemo.aw_blog_comment' doesn't exist";i:1;s:6048:"

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(516): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(563): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Manage/Comment/Grid.php(48): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): AW_Blog_Block_Manage_Comment_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/aw_blog/comments.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/M...')
#21 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/M...')
#32 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/community/AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/CommentController.php(55): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): AW_Blog_Manage_CommentController->indexAction()
#40 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imacdemo/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}";s:3:"url";s:89:"/imacdemo/index.php/blog_admin/manage_comment/index/key/b527c5e0e16bdf1d4fbd565e4e2fb127/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/imacdemo/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Did you try to contact the support team at Aheadworks? Maybe they already have a handy solution for the same

Comment: yes,no easy solution by them

Comment: can you edit your question and include the config file or the part that defines the observer in config?

Answer (score 0):

I added manually all tables. I found them in a old backup of the db.